# How to use spring autowiring in a testng factory class

Tags: java, spring, testng

Currently I have a factory class that looks like this:

```
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = BeanConfig.class)
        public class FactoryClass extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

            @Autowired
            public Bean bean;
            @Factory(dataProvider="dataProvider")
            public Object[] createTest(int a, int b) {
                return new Object[]{new FactoryTestClass(a, b)};
            }

            @DataProvider(name="dataProvider",parallel=true)
            public Object[][] passInts(){
                bean.method();
                return new Object[][]{{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,4}};
            }

            @BeforeSuite
            public void beforeSuite(){
                System.out.println("before suite");
            }
        }
```

My goal is to use spring's autowiring feature so i can use a bean to help generate some test data for the data provider. However in my attempt the spring context never initialises. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, or is there another approach I can take?

Thank you kindly,
Jason

Comment: How this BeanConfig looks like?

Comment: `@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.jason")
public class BeanConfig {
 @Autowired
 private Environment env;
}
`

Comment: @jbwt Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue: my test folder was located outside directory main, so, after I marked it as the Test Source Resource (in Intellij IDE) it started to work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to locate `@DataProvider` is same class as `@Test` method. I never had a problem with this approach.

Having various `@Test` methods and various `dataProvider`s in one test class is valid usage. `@Test` method will specify which dataProvider is used in `@Test` annotation parameter.

Example:

```
        @DataProvider(name="dataProvider",parallel=true)
        public Object[][] passInts(){
            bean.method();
            return new Object[][]{{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,4}};
        }

        @Test(dataProvier="dataProvider")
        public test(int param1, int param2){
            //...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks luboskrnac. I think that would work, however If I do this, then each test method will trigger the data provider to execute. Surely this might get unwieldy if I have several test methods?

Comment: No, TestNg is different. `@Test` method needs to specify `dataProvider` in annotation parameter. I commonly used various providers for various test methods per one test class. If test class is getting too big, class under test is probably handling too many concerns.

Comment: Thanks luboskrnac. If I have three test methods which are all annotated to use the same data provider, then the data provider method will be executed three times. I guess my problem with this is if the data provider method is expensive to run, which ends up slowing down tests. If I have a factory class and a data provider, then this method is only run once, which is why i'm attempting this approach in question!

Comment: Hmm. If you want to run it once, just call it in `@BeforeClass`.

Comment: If I put my data in a before class method, then I lose the ability to execute multiple test methods with different data parameters. I would have to have a giant test method which would iterate through the data generated in the before class method.

Comment: I don't understand. Why you want to execute same test method with 3 dataProviders? Why not to have dataProvider covering all test cases for that test method?

Comment: I would like to execute different test methods using the same data provider. When I have multiple test methods referencing one data provider, that one data provider method gets executed three times

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am also facing the similar issue?

Comment: If one data provider is used in three test methods, I believe it should be executed three times. Each run prepares test cases for each test method. Remember that provider may also return `Iterable<Object[]>` instead of `Object[][]`. So it theoretically may return different test cases for different test methods. So from my view, it's feature not issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class` to ContextConfiguration.